# Resize Image as Nine-Patch

Tags: java, graphics, nine-patch

I have seen many solutions on how to resize an image in java.

However, what I want to do is to have some parts of the image fixed and other stretchable in order to fit the content. This kind of functionality is given in the [Android Nine-Patch images](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html). Is there a way to achieve this in simple java?

```
 ____________      ___________________________
|            |    |                           |  
| Blah blah  | -> | Blah blah blah blah blah  |
|____    ____|    |___________    ____________|
     \  /                     \  /
      \/                       \/
```

The above is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: It would be fairly simple to replicate the effect.  Use `Graphics` or `Graphics2D` to tile the stretchable elements of the patches then paint the non-stretchable corner elements (all in a custom component).  Reading 'native format' nine-patch images is a separate matter.

Comment: Yes, this was the first workaround it came to mind. To have 3 seperate images with the middle one stable and the left/right image to be expandable. But I was hoping for something less painful!

Comment: *"Yes, this was the first workaround it came to mind."*  It didn't come to mind to mention that?  BTW - it is not a workaround.  It does pretty much what Android would have to do in order to render a nine-patch, except in core Java. *"..But I was hoping for something less painful!"*  Sometimes programmers need to ..write programs.  But then, that's why they pay us the 'big bucks'.  ;)